# Need help for a confirmation of a condition for future candles

Tags: pine-script

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to do it on pine script

I need to plot anything (triangle or line) when a candle meet an event.
What I'm analyzing are selling triggers. First, for identifying a trigger, I need a candle with high higher than the candle below and low higher than the candle below.
Now, for the confirmation, I need that a future candle closes below the low of the trigger, to confirm it. The problem is that the confirmation can occur right on the next candle or on the future candles.[this is an example of a trigger candle, and the line after it shows the moment of confirmation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFwoU.png)
Like on this image, I would like the code to plot something when a candle confirms the conditions

```
//@version=4
study(title="Eventos e Alerta", shorttitle="Eventos e Alerta", overlay=true)

// I tried this to overcome the problem of 'too many candles'
lookbackPeriod = 60

// First Event
primeiroEvento = high > high[1] and low > low[1]

// First event candle index
var int indicePrimeiroEvento = na
if primeiroEvento
    indicePrimeiroEvento := bar_index

//2nd event, candle closing below the low of first event
segundoEvento = close < low[indicePrimeiroEvento]



// plot
plotshape(series=segundoEvento and bar_index >= bar_index[indicePrimeiroEvento] - lookbackPeriod, title="Primeiro Evento", location=location.belowbar, color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown, size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var trig = 0.
higher_candle = high > high[1] and low > low[1]
if higher_candle
    trig := low
x = low < trig
plotshape(x, '', style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar)
```

if you need to plot only one time after condition just add line below:

```
trig := x ? 0 : trig
```